# Google Translate iframe workaround

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-translate, machine-translation

I'm using Google Translate tools to translate a web page and I also have an iframe on this page, that is not obviously translated with the page.

Is there a workaround, that any of you know, so I can have the iframe translated as well?

Answer (score 12):

This is a genuine limitation or policy of Google Translate. You can't rewrite iframe content. But one thing you can do is change `iframe` url to translated page like:

```
<iframe height="1200" width="600" src="http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=bg&ie=UTF-8&u=YOUR_IFRAME_URL&sl=de&tl=bg" align="middle" border="0">
```

Comment: any other app in chrome store which translates the content in iframe ? or using some kind of proxy ? as i cannot change the url with in the iframe

Comment: in fact you can if it's from the same domain

Comment: A couple of decades later in dog years and the Bing link no longer works. Is this a suitable substitute? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/translator-text-api/

Answer (score 1):

If you need to translate the page with iframes, you can:

**1. Use Bing Translator, that proxyfies request, so it wouldn't be cross domain.**

> site:
>
> https://www.bing.com/translator
>
> plugin that uses it (not tested):
>
> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/translator/blndkmebkmenignoajhoemebccmmfjib

**2. You can run your browser (if it's Chrome) with `--disable-web-security` param, so it would allow access to frames from other domains.**

> Please note that it's dangerous and should only be used on trusted
>   sites.

Comment: I cannot use bing translator, as i have login in to site which gets the information from another site and in an iframe, i have tried with proxy to change the url as suggested below, but it is not working :(

Comment: Check the second solution then. There is no other effective way to force google translator to skip  cross domain policy.

Comment: What do you get in console? any errors? if not, there has to be a precheck of origin, and there is no simple way to skip it.

Comment: i do not see any errors when trying to translate, only when I refresh the page as i have enabled the always translate mode. '[1:1:0427/131535:ERROR:render_media_log.cc(25)] MediaEvent: PIPELINE_ERROR demuxer: could not open
'

Comment: Command for option 2 was: "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" --user-data-dir=./chrome --disable-web-security but did not work for me.

Comment: The Google Translator code have totally changed. Now it translates chunks, only visible area. You would have to look for triggers and manually shoot them. That would probably require a custom browser extension.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create empty iframe.
2. Ajax the second iframe content already translated by google translator.
3. Dump the response of the ajax into empty iframe.

$("#id_of_empty_iframe").load("http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=bg&ie=UTF-8&u=YOUR_IFRAME_URL&sl=de&tl=bg");

Answer (score -1):

You could create a layer and put the translator code in it and put the layer `top` `-500` so it hides the layer off the page with the Google dropdown selector in it.