# google translate element does not translate iframe if src is changed to another local page

Tags: javascript, google-translate

Google translate element does translate an iframe on my page only the first time it is loaded. If I load another page in the iframe the page is not translated in most browsers (e.g. Chrome). I can't use [Google Translate iframe workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936421/google-translate-iframe-workaround) because the resulting webpage can't be displayed in an iframe (it seems that google uses a framekiller).

Here is my code:

```
<div id="google">
    <span id="google_translate_element"></span> <span style="float: left;">
        <script id="translate1">
            function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                googleTranslate = new google.translate.TranslateElement({
                    pageLanguage : 'de'
                }, 'google_translate_element');
            }
        </script> 
        <script id="translate2"
            src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">
        </script>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the iframe from your domain, or another website?

Comment: It is from the same domain (a local path is given as source).

Answer (score 0):

The translated page cannot be displayed in an iframe because of an [X-Frame-Options: DENY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) header in the response sent by google translate.

My solution is to implement a route on your server to fetch a translated page, and then have an iframe

```
<iframe src="/translate?url=targetUrl"></iframe>
```

You could get around the X-Frame-Options: DENY header by implementing a route on your server to grab the content and forward it to the user, like so (in Python, with Flask):

```
def get_translate_url(url):
    return "http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=bg&ie=UTF-8&u=%s&sl=de&tl=en" % url

@app.route('/translate')
def grabContentForMyIframe():
    url = request.args.get(url)
    response = requests.get(get_translate_url(url))
    return response.content
```

Comment: how do I implement this route on my Strato server? Which file do I have to edit?

Comment: The operating system is SunOS gaffer 5.10 Generic_142901-13 i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris .

Comment: I don't think you can, because Strato looks like it is only for Wordpress / static files -- you don't have server-side code. So my answer does is not an answer. Apologies.

Comment: I can load php with my server! The only problem is that flask is not installed....

Comment: The behaviour of googletranslate is quite erratic. Sometimes it translates an iframe sometimes it doesn't.