# Making Google-Translate plugin not track visitors unless they ask it to

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I want to implement GoogleTranslate plugin on my personal website. However, I don't want Google to be able to track all visitors of my site, through their script; unless my visitors decide to use that functionality.

I include Google's code below, as I am supposed to paste it in the body of my page:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>




I would appreciate to have specific code to use, not just an explanation. Basically, I want Google's script to load only when a visitor decides s/he wants to use it and actually clicks on it.
```

Answer (score 1):

This code below will not load the script from Google's servers until the "Load Google Translate" button is pressed.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function loadGoogleTranslate() {
        var scriptTag = document.createElement('script'); 
        scriptTag.type = "text/javascript"; 
        scriptTag.src = "//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"; 
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; 
        head.appendChild(scriptTag);
      }

      function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        // Hide the section containing the "Load Google Translate" button
        var beforeLoadSection = document.getElementById('before-load');
        beforeLoadSection.style.display = 'none';

        // Set up Google Translate now that their script has loaded
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');

        // Show the section containing the Google Translate element
        var afterLoadSection = document.getElementById('after-load');
        afterLoadSection.style.display = '';
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="before-load">
      <button onclick="window.loadGoogleTranslate()">Load Google Translate</button>
    </div>
    <div id="after-load" style="display:none">
      <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can verify that the Google script is not loaded until the button is clicked by watching network traffic (in the "Network" tab of [Chrome's DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open) for example).

Note you can also just create a link like this one that users can click on to access a translated version of your page, no fancy Javascript required:
[https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=**en**&tl=**ar**&u=**https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fq%2F55643969%2F3063273**](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=en&tl=ar&u=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fq%2F55643969%2F3063273)

I bolded the parts you'll need to worry about:

- **en** is the "from" language (English in this case)
- **ar** is the "to" language (Arabic in this case)
- **long string of text** is the [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) form of the page to translate. Google "URL encode" if you want to learn how to do that. Javascript has a built-in function that might help

P.S. You probably got a downvote from someone because they don't like "write-my-code" types of questions. If you had instead included [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then you probably wouldn't have been downvoted, but creating an MCVE can be really difficult if you have no idea where to even start. Here's some additional reading on that subject if you want to learn more about the culture around here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345249/3063273

P.P.S. If you want to use the above fancy-pants Javascript code, keep in mind that [you can't use it in an `iframe`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22936421/3063273). If you don't know what an `iframe` is then don't worry about this.

Comment: Hi mate, and thanks a lot for this. Another question: Which of all this should I copy on each of the pages of my site in order to keep them translateable? (providing I still keep my visitor's privacy respected)

Comment: @AndreasA. Ahoy! You should be able to copy the contents of the `<head>` section (i.e. the `<script>` element and its contents) into each page's `<head>` section, and the contents of `<body>` section (i.e. the two `<div>` elements and their contents) into each page's `<body>` section. If you're using PHP (or similar) it might be wise to put those two snippets of HTML into PHP functions that are then reused across your pages, instead of copying and pasting HTML into each page. That way you write less, have fewer opportunities to create bugs, and fewer places to fix any bugs or change stuff :)